# get all the HTTP headers from HTTP server response in libevent

Tags: c, http, libevent

Using libevent to do HTTP request.  I would like to print all the HTTP headers in the server response, but not sure how.

```
static void http_request_done(struct evhttp_request *req, void *ctx) {
    //how do I print out all the http headers in the server response 
}

evhttp_request_new(http_request_done,NULL);
```

I know I can get an individual header like the following, but how do I get all the headers?

```
static void http_request_done(struct evhttp_request *req, void *ctx) {
    struct evkeyvalq * kv = evhttp_request_get_input_headers(req);
    printf("%s\n", evhttp_find_header(kv, "SetCookie"));
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though I don't have any previous experience with `libevent` library, it's rather clear for me that API doesn't provide such functionality (see its [API](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-2.0/doxygen/html/http_8h.html) for reference). However what you can do is to write your own method using `TAILQ_FOREACH` internal macro, which is defined in `event-internal.h`. Definition of `evhttp_find_header` is rather straightforward:

```
const char *
evhttp_find_header(const struct evkeyvalq *headers, const char *key)
{
    struct evkeyval *header;

    TAILQ_FOREACH(header, headers, next) {
        if (evutil_ascii_strcasecmp(header->key, key) == 0)
            return (header->value);
    }

    return (NULL);
}
```

Instead of doing `evutil_ascii_strcasecmp` you can just simply obtain `header->key` or `header->value` entries from `evkeyval` struct (defined in `include/event2/keyvalq_struct.h`):

```
/*
 * Key-Value pairs.  Can be used for HTTP headers but also for
 * query argument parsing.
 */
struct evkeyval {
    TAILQ_ENTRY(evkeyval) next;

    char *key;
    char *value;
};
```

Comment: thanks @Grzegorz Szpetkowski for the quick response,  I don't have "event-internal.h" in the /usr/local/include/event2. I can copy event-internal.h to the directory but hesitated because that's more like a kludge.

Comment: @codingFun: This is "hard-way" method, so it reqires to download libevent source, thus requires manual compilation. As I checked definition should be put in `http.c` and appriopriate declaration (prototype) in `include/event2/http.h` (you probably using it in your program).

Comment: it's a little strange that my program can compile as long as I don't use the macro TAILQ_FOREACH. Seems that  the macro is ONLY in the internal header files. What do you think?

Comment: @codingFun: It's internal function-like macro, not intended to be exposed to public API (so your program doesn't compile), essentially is just a `for` loop with another `TAILQ_FIRST`, `TAILQ_END`, `TAILQ_NEXT` f-l macros.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to helpful tips from @Grzegorz Szpetkowski,  I created the following routine which works fine. The reason that "kv = kv->next.tqe_next" was used was because of "TAILQ_ENTRY(evkeyval) next" in the definition of struct evkeyval.

```
static void http_request_done(struct evhttp_request *req, void *ctx) {
    struct evkeyvalq *header = evhttp_request_get_input_headers(req);
    struct evkeyval* kv = header->tqh_first;
    while (kv) {
        printf("%s: %s\n", kv->key, kv->value);
        kv = kv->next.tqe_next;
    }
}
```